# Taking inverse of a matrix of function

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'd like to take the inverse of the A martix

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[0.1], [0.1], [-0.1]])

x, y, z = sp.symbols("x y z")


eq1 = 3*x - sp.cos(y*z) - 1/2
eq2 = x**2 -81*(y+0.1)**2 + sp.sin(z) + 1.06
eq3 = sp.exp(-x*y) + 20*z + (10*np.pi - 3)/3

A = np.array([[0,0,x],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

f = np.array([[eq1],[eq2],[eq3]])

A[0,0] = sp.diff(eq1,x)
A[1,0] = sp.diff(eq1,y)
A[2,0] = sp.diff(eq1,z)
A[0,1] = sp.diff(eq2,x)
A[1,1] = sp.diff(eq2,y)
A[2,1] = sp.diff(eq2,z)
A[0,2] = sp.diff(eq3,x)
A[1,2] = sp.diff(eq3,y)
A[2,2] = sp.diff(eq3,z)
print(A)

J = np.linalg.inv(A)
print(A)
```

However, the built-in function doesn't work. So how can I take the inverse of it?

Comment: Have you tried using numpy's inverse? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html

Comment: Yes that was my initial step but that didn't work.

Comment: sympy.array doesn't work unfortunately so I had to do it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use sympy matrix instead:

```
J = sp.Matrix(A).inv()
```

Comment: It is giving me a crazy value but I'm guessing it's correct. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yep, it's quite a mess but if you check in wolframalpha is correct. Can you please consider accepting the answer?

Comment: It's supposed to be a 3 by 3 matrix but the answer isn't for me. So can you upload a screenshot of it in wolfram alpha?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I cant' post a sreenshot here, but have you checked `J.shape`?

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize matrix A using sympy rather than numpy array it will work.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix

b = np.array([[0.1], [0.1], [-0.1]])

x, y, z = sp.symbols("x y z")


eq1 = 3*x - sp.cos(y*z) - 1/2
eq2 = x**2 -81*(y+0.1)**2 + sp.sin(z) + 1.06
eq3 = sp.exp(-x*y) + 20*z + (10*np.pi - 3)/3

f = np.array([[eq1],[eq2],[eq3]])

a1 = sp.diff(eq1,x)
b1 = sp.diff(eq1,y)
c1 = sp.diff(eq1,z)
a2 = sp.diff(eq2,x)
b2 = sp.diff(eq2,y)
c2 = sp.diff(eq2,z)
a3 = sp.diff(eq3,x)
b3 = sp.diff(eq3,y)
c3 = sp.diff(eq3,z)
print(A)

A = Matrix( [[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]])   # Initialize using sympy Matrix

A_inverse = A.inv()
print(A_inverse)
```

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a numpy array, object dtype, containing `sympy` objects:

```
In [5]: A                                                                                      
Out[5]: 
array([[3, 2*x, -y*exp(-x*y)],
       [z*sin(y*z), -162*y - 16.2, -x*exp(-x*y)],
       [y*sin(y*z), cos(z), 20]], dtype=object)

In [6]: np.linalg.inv(A)                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ae645f97e1f8> in <module>
----> 1 np.linalg.inv(A)

<__array_function__ internals> in inv(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in inv(a)
    545     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    546     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 547     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    548     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    549 

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv
```

`np.linalg` works for numeric arrays, not general Python objects.

Math on object dtype arrays is hit-or-miss.  Somethings work, but many don't.  Mixing sympy and numpy is generally not recommended.

A row sum does work - because the sympy objects can 'add' themselves:

```
In [7]: A.sum(axis=1)                                                                          
Out[7]: 
array([2*x - y*exp(-x*y) + 3, 
       -x*exp(-x*y) - 162*y + z*sin(y*z) - 16.2,
       y*sin(y*z) + cos(z) + 20
       ], dtype=object)
```

That numpy array can be made into a sparse matrix, as other show:

```
In [10]: As = Matrix(A.tolist() )                                                              

In [11]: As                                                                                    
Out[11]: 
⎡                               -x⋅y⎤
⎢    3            2⋅x       -y⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎢                               -x⋅y⎥
⎢z⋅sin(y⋅z)  -162⋅y - 16.2  -x⋅ℯ    ⎥
⎢                                   ⎥
⎣y⋅sin(y⋅z)     cos(z)         20   ⎦
```

and the inverse exists - but it is (3,3), but the elements are large expressions:

```
In [12]: As.inv()                         
...
In [14]: _12.shape                                                                             
Out[14]: (3, 3)

In [15]: As.det()                                                                                      
Out[15]: 
     2    -x⋅y                                   -x⋅y           2                  -x⋅y      
- 2⋅x ⋅y⋅ℯ    ⋅sin(y⋅z) - 40⋅x⋅z⋅sin(y⋅z) + 3⋅x⋅ℯ    ⋅cos(z) + y ⋅(-162⋅y - 16.2)⋅ℯ    ⋅sin(y

           -x⋅y                                 
⋅z) - y⋅z⋅ℯ    ⋅sin(y⋅z)⋅cos(z) - 9720⋅y - 972.0
```

Comment: What do you expect from `numpy`? As the `sympy` inverse shows, the algebraic answer is messy.  `numpy` is for numbers, not algebra. If you want to assign specific numbers to `x,y,z` we can get a numeric inverse, either with sympy or numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can do numpy operations like inv on SymPy expressions. However, I don’t use SymPy.

Also, not all matrices are [invertable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).